# android emulator net access stopped after some minutes of working

Tags: android-emulator

While working with my app that require network access...

The Android 2.2 emulator's network connection stop working...

The net was working properly but after some time it did not respond on emulator,

while it was working f9 on my system...

I have cross checked the net connections and restarted with the emulator(even created a new avd ). But the problem remains same my net is not working on emulator..

I have also checked the connection with F8  key on emulator...

My app manifest net permission is enabled....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally After all I have myself found the solution of to the problem:

It's very common problem that must have been faced by most of android developers....

Recently, while developing an Android Application, I was faced with a situation that wasted 2 hours of my time.  The issue was simple, my app was not able to access internet from the Android Emulator.

Initially I thought fixing the issue should have been straight forward, but life is not always that simple.

So what was the real issue because of which my app was not able to access internet?  There are multiple reasons because of which this issue could occur.  Hence, I decided to document my findings so that other could benefit from it.

There are two main symptoms of no internet connection on android emulator.....
***Only your app is not able to access the internet
***None of the apps are able to access the internet
Lets look at what are the reasons behind each of them.

Only your app is not able to access the internet

If only your app is not able to access the internet on the emulator, check if any other apps are able to access the internet or not.  For e.g. you could open up the browser application, visit http://news.google.com/.  If the page opens up correctly then problem lies in your app itself and its simple to fix.

Basically, your app needs the Permission to access the internet.  This can be done by adding the following line just before the end of  tag in AndroidManifest.xml file of your application.

Compile and re-install the app in the emulator and try to access the internet from your app. It should work!

What is the use of uses-permission tag:

Android application can request certain permissions so that they can function properly.  Some examples of permissions are, get users location, make a call, access the internet etc. App has to explicitly specify this in the AndroidManifest.xml.

When end users install such an app on their device, the android OS will notify the user that, app is requesting certain permissions.  If users are fine with that, then only the app will be installed.  Else users can deny the permission and the app will not be installed.

This mechanism is Androids way of implementing security and users privacy!

**This is the more tricky situation:**
None of the apps are able to access the internet

Now this situation is tricky.  There are two reasons because of which this could happen
Proxy server is not configured on the emulator
Incorrect DNS used by the emulator

**Setting Up the DNS Server:
emulator.exe -avd 'android1.6' -dns-server 8.8.8.8**

The android1.6 is your avd name I created an avd with name android1.6

So just replace android1.6 with your avd name.

Run this code in command prompt after setting the path to tools & platform tools of your android sdk

Comment: I have been struggling a lot.. and then finally got the solution after detailed study.So posting the solution